# Problem when modifying a copy of slice from DataFrame. (feat. numpy.where)

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

Why does warning occur when modifying a copy of `Pandas.dataframe`? And why doesn't warning occur when modifying using `numpy.where`? (df = DataFrame Object)

Warning Code

```
[186] df = input_df.copy()
[187] df['trade_status'][df['trade_status'] == 'DONE'] = 'FILLED'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Practice\Report\src\service\ReportService.py:187: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

No Warning Code

```
[186] df = input_df.copy()
[187] df['trade_status'] = np.where(df['trade_status'] == 'DONE', 'FILLED', df['trade_status'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Clear
```

Comment: `np.where` creates a new Series.  It's values replace the whole of `df['trade_status']`.  `where` is not an in-place iterator.  The assignment occurs after it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `df = input_df.copy()` is indeed a new DataFrame.
In this point you are right.

But you don't operate on it directly.
Note that `df['trade_status'][df['trade_status'] == 'DONE']` creates a **view**
of *df*.

So when you attempt to save a new value there (`… = 'FILLED'`), the exception is raised.